# How to redirect the kickstart output to the serial console?

Tags: centos, kickstart

I am trying to automate a server build using HP's ILO virtual serial interface to avoid the advanced license.

When the kickstart file is running, none of the output is sent to the serial console.

Including the following in the kickstart file will redirect the installed OS output to serial as desired but only after the kickstart has completed.
`bootloader --append="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 "`

Is there a way to configure the Kickstart file to send its output to the serial console so the output can be monitored via VSP on ILO?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it looks like I can set it in the menu item for the patch

Add `console=ttyS0`

```
menuentry 'Autoinstall CentOS Stream 8-stream' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
+       linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-dvd quiet inst.ks=hd:LABEL=CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-dvd:/ks.cfg nomodeset console=ttyS0
+       initrdefi /images/pxeboot/initrd.img
```